# SharePoint client SendMail

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I have the following code (this is a simplified test) in a console application running under my own user account (contoso\test):

### Update

I added a try catch and some exception handling. The last catch block is triggered. In my ULSlog it says SmtpException but it doesn't catch that one

```
            try
            {

                var ClientContext = new ClientContext(siteUri);
                var emailProps = new EmailProperties();
                List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
                userNames.Add("contoso\\test");
                emailProps.To = userNames;
                emailProps.Subject = "Subject";
                emailProps.Body = "Test";
                Utility.SendEmail(ClientContext, emailProps);
                ClientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                WriteToEventLog("SmtpException" + smtpEx.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioEx)
            {
                WriteToEventLog("IOException" + ioEx.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException socketEx)
            {
                WriteToEventLog("SocketException" + socketEx.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Exception" + e.StackTrace);
            }
```

In 1 in a 200 times the SendMail gives me the following exception:

```
Exception Info: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(System.IO.Stream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ChunkStringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext, Int32, Int32, System.String)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext, Int32, Int32, System.String)
   at RemindingEmailTimerJob.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

I want to run this code as a Windows Scheduled task. When I configure the task and let this task run under my own user account (contoso\test) the SendMail gives me the same exception 75% of the time.

### Update

I see these errors in my ULS

```
Original error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    
 at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    
 at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)    
 at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)    
 at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendEmail_Client(EmailProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.Utilities.SPUtilityServerStub.InvokeStaticMethod(String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeStaticMethodWithMonitoredScope(String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeStaticMethod(String typeId, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStaticMethod(XmlElement xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()
```

And

```
 SocialRESTExceptionProcessingHandler.DoServerExceptionProcessing - SharePoint Server Exception [System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    
 at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    
 at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)    
 at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)    
 at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendEmail_Client(EmailProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.Utilities.SPUtilityServerStub.InvokeStaticMethod(String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeStaticMethodWithMonitoredScope(String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeStaticMethod(String typeId, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStaticMethod(XmlElement xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()]
```

Anybody any idea?

### Update

I tried to test my code with another development SMTP server. I was using Smtp4Dev. I tried installing hMailServer and now my code is no longer giving errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the try catch and logging to identify the issue...

```
$ErrorMessage = ""
Try
{
   //your code goes here
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Break
}
Finally
{
    $Time=Get-Date
    "This script made a read attempt at $Time" +  $ErrorMessage  | out-file d:\errorlog.log -append
}
```

You can also use native PowerShell (**Net.Mail.SmtpClient** or **Send-MailMessage** ) to send email

Net.Mail.SmtpClient

```
$smtpServer = "XXXXX"
$smtpFrom = "XXXXX"
$smtpTo = "XXXXX"
$messageSubject = "XXXXX"
$messageBody = "XXXXX"

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$messagesubject,$messagebody)
```

Send-MailMessage

```
$smtpServer = "XXXXX"
$emailFrom = "XXXXX"
$emailTo = "XXXXX"
$emailSubject = "XXXXX"
$emailBody = @"
Here is a message
XXXXX
"@
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer
```

Make sure sender and receiver have email addresses, i.e. not null :)

Comment: I tried the try catch. See my updated example and uls log. In uls I see a smtp exception but my catch for that doesn't do anything. I get into the last catch block

Comment: I suggest to `ClientContext.Dispose()` in finally block. Did you try PowerShell version that I posted above?

Comment: Yes from PowerShell no issues. From Visual Studio no issues. Starting console from explorer no issues. From scheduled task I do have issues. I did solve the problem by using another test mail server on my development server. I was using Smtp4Dev and now I am using hMailServer

Comment: Excellent it worked out in the end, you may mark this post as answer :)